# Faster method to read and append multiple columns from a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

My files have multiple columns and I store them in lists for later use. But sometimes I don't know how many columns there are exactly so I have to continuously adjust the number of lists I define.

Hence I was wondering if there is there is a faster approach to define an *n* number of lists so I don't have to worry about appending each and every one of them like I am doing below?

```
col_header = []    
c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10, c11 = [[] for i in range(11)]
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for i, row in enumerate(reader):
            if i == 0:
                col_header.append(row)
            elif len(row)!=0:
                c1.append(float(row[0]))
                c2.append(float(row[1]))
                c3.append(float(row[2]))
                c4.append(float(row[3]))
                c5.append(float(row[4]))
        #etc..
```

Comment: `c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10, c11 = [[] for i in range(11)]` is a bad idea for starters. Why not call your left term `c` and use indexes

Comment: or you can use a dictionary  `cols = {'c1':[], 'c2':[], ...}` and if you need an other column you update the dictionary (`cols.update({'cX':[]}`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, you should set your columns, to a list, this could be a good start.

```
col_header = []

def create_columns(n):
    list_of_columns = []
    for i in range(n):
        list_of_columns.append([])

    return list_of_columns

columns = create_columns(10)
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        if i == 0:
            col_header.append(row)
        elif len(row)!=0:
            for index, col in enumerate(columns):
                col.append(float(row[index]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list_of_lists =[c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10, c11]   
for list in list_of_lists:
   list.append(float(row[0]))
```

Note that in Python, the code

```
list0 = [value0]
list_of_list[0] = list0
list_of_list[0].append(value1)
print(list0)
```

will output [value0,value2]; list_of_list doesn't contain a copy of list0, but a reference to list0, so changing list_of_list[0] also changes list0.

You could also use Panda DataFrames or numPy arrays, and then you wouldn't have to deal with all these for loops, you could just use pd.read_csv and then append that dataframe to the original.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a list `c` that contains all of `c1, c2, c3...`